# Why is QGIS (resource sharing plugin) telling me that R (3.4.4-1ubuntu1) is not installed?

Tags: qgis, r, qgis-plugins

This morning I went to install the R Processing scripts to my installation of QGIS3.12 (on linux Mint 19.3) and although the Resource Sharing plugin installs the resources required and the scripts appear in the Processing pane, I am told that R is not installed when it is (first image below)

The dialog that appears is in the second image.

Relatedly, the third image below shows my Options for the R provision with an altered R directory (as per comments' suggestions). When these settings are confirmed, QGIS crashes and leaves the following crash report:

```
The package providing /newroot/app/bin/qgis could not be found.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's in your Settings... Options... Providers> R> section look like? It should have a setting for your "R Folder" which is where your R executable is - usually something like `/usr/bin/R`.

Comment: My R folder is at [/home/eoin/R]. This folder has sub-folders, the main one of which is [x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library]

Comment: That's where your R library is, and should probably be related to the "User library folder" setting. If you do `which R` at the terminal command line it should tell you where your R executable comes from, something like `/usr/bin/R`. In which case `/usr/bin/` needs to go in the "R folder" setting.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. A terminal command 'which R' yields [/usr/bin/R]. I changed the 'R folder' setting to /usr/bin/ and when I click ok, I get a brief python (!) error message which I cannot read and then the program crashes.

Comment: [img]https://i.imgur.com/yGbbQFF.jpg[/img]

Comment: it does look like an old version of R.... Can you edit your question to show the R version and the image you put in the comment, as well as the updated info about the python error and any details of the crash?